# why laravel sessions gets expired after login instantly?

Tags: laravel, session, expired-sessions

```
if(Auth::guard('runner')->attempt(['email'=> $request->email,'password'=>$request->password])) {
         
           return redirect()->route('home');
        }

// this is my route 

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home')->middleware('runner');

// this is my middleware in middleware it gives null but after login it gives user data

 $user = Auth::guard('runner')->user();
  

        if($user) {
            // Log::info('Authenticated runner in middleware:', ['runner' => $user]);
            return $next($request);
        }
```

//  i tried to clear cache , I tried with SESSION_DRIVER=file and database as well also with the SESSION_LIFETIME

Comment: How have you configured the `runner` guard?

Comment: yes i configured the runner in auth.php
it was working fine but suddenly this happens